# Android toolchain - develop for Android devices flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
cmdline-tools component is missing
Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
i got this proplem whem install flutter and iam install cmd android tool from android studio

flutter works after this proplem